# Databinding, view is visible at start. Altho' Observable is False

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-livedata, android-databinding

I have this value:

```
   val communicationIsExpanded = ObservableField<Boolean>(false)
```

I have a LiveDataObserver, set on a ViewModel item. And I have this implementation on property changed:

```
private inner class OnPropertyChangedCallbackImpl : Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {

    override fun onPropertyChanged(sender: Observable, propertyId: Int) {
        renderChange()
    }
}

fun renderChange() {
    communicationIsExpanded.set(communication?.isExpanded)
}
```

But whenever my list is initialised, for a couple of seconds (1-2) until data is loaded, my view is always visible. This is how I init it.

```
<com.xelion.android.view.MediaController
        android:id="@+id/MediaController"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_default"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:visibility="@{nameProps.communicationIsExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/missedCommunicationCounter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

My observable Boolean is init with false at start. So What is causing this view to be Visible, at start?

Comment: have you bind your model to the view? can you share that snippet

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65827036/9701793) may answer the question