# How can I set a ConstraintLayout Group's visibility via DataBinding?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-databinding

I have 2 `Group`s in my layout which control the visibility of my Views.
However, I cannot set their visibility via DataBinding:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="co.aresid.book13.fragments.trackinglist.TrackingListViewModel"
            />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        ...

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/content_group"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.hideLoadingAndShowContent ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=gone}"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="tracking_list_recycler_view"
            />
        
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/loading_group"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.hideLoadingAndShowContent ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE, default=visible}"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="progress_circular"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

The `hideLoadingAndShowContent` variable is a `LiveData` which gets its value from a corresponding `MutableLiveData` in my `ViewModel`:

```
private val _hideLoadingAndShowContent = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val hideLoadingAndShowContent: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _hideLoadingAndShowContent
```

This `LiveData` is only set in the `ViewModel` and does not occur in the `Fragment` class.
In the `Fragment` class, I have also set the `binding.lifecycleOwner`:

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
```

What detail am I missing out?

Comment: can you add the code kotlin snippet where inflate view and setviewmodel to binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to pass the `ViewModel` to the layout binding in my `Fragment` class:

```
binding.viewModel = viewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that `android:visibility` does not support binding variable observation,

You can create BindingAdapter this way

```
@BindingAdapter("mutableVisibility")
fun setMutableVisibility(view: View, visibility: MutableLiveData<Boolean>) {
    val owner = (view.getParentActivity() ?: view.context) as LifecycleOwner
    if (owner != null) {
        visibility.observe(
            owner,
            Observer { value ->
                  view.visibility = if(value) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            })
    }
}
```

Utility function for getting activity from view.

```
fun View.getParentActivity(): AppCompatActivity?{
    var context = this.context
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is AppCompatActivity) {
            return context
        }
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    return null
}
```

Then in your XML you can do it like

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/content_group"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.hideLoadingAndShowContent}"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="tracking_list_recycler_view"
            />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, that seems not to be true: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#common_features. I have also read another SO question where it works the way I did it.

Comment: Well it takes some effort to answer, voting  down the answer without even testing discourages the answerer

Comment: @RenéSpies what you said is true but it works one time, when binding happens when you bind the field or model with viewdatabinding object, then it won't, so for live data where the value will change at runtime, you can do that with Bindingadapter.

Comment: @RenéSpies I know but, someone did.

Comment: can you share the piece of code where you bind viewmodel

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: your kotlin/java code where you setview and attach the datamodel to the view

Comment: Oh right. I never passed the `ViewModel` to the layout binding. Thank you, now it works

Comment: I hope you would appreciate the effort